# Export dataframe as csv file from google colab to google drive

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory, drive

I want to upload a dataframe as csv from colab to google drive.I tried a lot but no luck. I can upload a simple text file but failed to upload a csv.

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2,3]})
df.to_csv('abc',sep='\t')
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'sample.csv', 'mimeType':'csv'})
uploaded.SetContentFile('abc')
uploaded.Upload()
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem? where did you get stuck? please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 47):

It may be easier to use mounting instead of pydrive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('drive')
```

After authentication, you can copy your csv file.

```
df.to_csv('data.csv')
!cp data.csv "drive/My Drive/"
```

Comment: thank you, this works fine, I would just like to know what does the line '!cp data.csv drive/My\ Drive/' do?

Comment: It copy data.csv from current directory to your gdrive (mounted at drive/My Drive/ )

Comment: is it possible to copy the file to the folder the colab file is in?

Answer (score 24):

Without using !cp command

`from google.colab import  drive`

- Mounts the google drive to Colab Notebook

`drive.mount('/drive')`

- Make sure the folder Name is created in the google drive before uploading

`df.to_csv('/drive/My Drive/folder_name/name_csv_file.csv')`

Answer (score 11):

```py
# Import Drive API and authenticate.
from google.colab import drive

# Mount your Drive to the Colab VM.
drive.mount('/gdrive')

# Write the DataFrame to CSV file.
with open('/gdrive/My Drive/foo.csv', 'w') as f:
  df.to_csv(f)
```

Answer (score 8):

The other answers almost worked but I needed a small tweak:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('drive')

df.to_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/filename.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

the `/content/` bit proved necessary

Comment: same here. None of the above worked but found same solution [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/exporting-dataframe-as-csv-file-from-google-colab-to-google-drive/). At first I thought it had to do with the language setting of my Google account. But wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save locally then you can use this

```
f.to_csv('sample.csv')
from google.colab import files
files.download("sample.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to work with Pandas, do this:

```
df_mini.coalesce(1)\
   .write\
   .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
   .options(header='true', delimiter='\t')\
   .save('gdrive/My Drive/base_mini.csv')
```