# translate dataframe python to english and save the result into a cvs file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 205232 rows, i want to translate the column 'ingredients_text' which can contain 1 or more languages in a single row to english. This is an example of the df

[image]

I I tried the translation with two ways but it didn't work:
code 1:

```
import googletrans    
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['transalted']= df['ingredients_text'].apply(translator.translate ,dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
#then i want to save the result into a csv file
```

code 2:

```
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
for column in df['ingredients_text']: 
   translation=translator.translate(column, dest='fr').text
#then i want to save the result into a csv file
```

I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `apply()` with lambda function. Then use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to convert dataframe to csv.

```py
import googletrans    
from googletrans import Translator


translator = Translator()
df['transalted'] = df['ingredients_text'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)

df.to_csv('your.csv')

# If you only want translated result,
# you can use
df['transalted'].to_csv('your.csv')
```

Comment: the traslation works well, but save it in csv makes an error : OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: 'translated.csv'

Comment: @Yoss `df.to_csv('your.csv')` and `df['transalted'].to_csv('your.csv')` which one are you using? You only need to choose one of them.

Comment: i need to save all the df => df.to_csv('your.csv') , i'm using google colab

Comment: @Yoss I don't use google colab. Check [Export dataframe as csv file from google colab to google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898836) for pandas exportation.